# Selenium IDE Using stored variable in javascript command

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-ide

I want to create a JavaScript date using text I stored from my site. 
This is what I tried:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeValue</td>
    <td>name=contract_additional_fields[agreement_created_date]</td>
    <td>seleniumContractDateValue</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>javascript{Date.parse('${seleniumContractDateValue}')}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I also tried using nothing or "" in the parse but neither one worked.

Can anyone help me figure out how I use a stored variable as a parameter of a JavaScript command?

Answer (score 2):

1.you access variables with "storedVars['seleniumContractDateValue']" in JavaScript.

2.Selenium won't store a JavaScript date object, so you will need to parse it into a string as well.

```
<tr>
    <td>storeValue</td>
    <td>name=contract_additional_fields[agreement_created_date]</td>
    <td>seleniumContractDateValue</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>javascript{Date.parse(storedVars['seleniumContractDateValue'])}</td>
    <td>seleniumContractDateValue</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${seleniumContractDateValue}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```